# why visibility is always setted to visible although in CSS is hidden?

Tags: javascript, css, styles, visibility

I am using ShadowBox for showing media. It has some property **showOverlay**, which i setted to false, because dont need it.
Problem is that background is not accesible as if ShadowBox is  modal dialog although Visibility in CSS is setted as **hidden**. 
In Chrome and Mozilla it will be changed to **visible** and is modal. It works manually if me changing it back again to **hidden**.

BUT WHY it is always setted to **visible** in Chrome and Mozilla browsers sourcepage/css????

Here are my **CSS of ShadowBox**:

```
#sb-container {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: left;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
}

#sb-overlay {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    visibility:hidden;
}

#sb-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100px;
}
```

and it is what **Chrome and Mozilla does**! in Explorer it works!
[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline styles (the ones on `element.style`) have a greater "priority" over CSS styles defined in a stylesheet.

What you can do:

- It's a good advice to actually avoid inline styles if possible. Style your elements with the least specificity at best. That way, they're easily overridable later on.

  Note that changing styles via JS (`someElement.style.someStyleHere`) counts as an inline style as well.
- If you are changing styles dynamically, it is better to define the styles in CSS classes, and use JS to dynamically add or remove these classes on the target elements.

  If you are familiar with jQuery, the [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) are the functions I'm referencing. Of course, you can come up with your own function that parses the element's `className`, and add or remove the said classes.
- If avoiding inline styles isn't an option (due to some framework you use that does it that way), you can override inline styles by placing `!important` on your styles defined in your stylesheet. It's a bit rash, and usually used as a last resort to overthrow inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot it appears that `visiblity: visible` is set as a `style` inside the `style` attribute on the element. The `style` attribute always overrides what is inside any stylesheets.

Comment: If you absolutely must override it in CSS and you cannot override the `style` attribute then you can use `visibility: hidden !important;`.

Comment: @RagimsRagimovs Stop using JavaScript?  If there are no inline styles in your markup, that's where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

try using `visibility: hidden !important;`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple and interesting concept in CSS called [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

It defines to the browser which CSS rule to be applied in case of overriding of rules.

In your case, you have applied inline CSS style to your html elements. Since it has the highest priority, whatever your write in your external .css file will be ignored.

To avoid this, remove all inline css from your html code and try to incorporate them in the external css file you having. OR as many people already suggested, you can use the "!important" to your greatest advantage.

Hope this clears out the problem.